# Split returns PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence

Tags: java, regex

When a user input contains Unicode characters (e.g. ***‘*** or ***”*** ), the following action fails:

`String[] unicodeStrings = answerText.split("((?<=\\R)|(?=\\R))");`

I've tried debugging the split method, but I haven't found the root cause. I have a hunch it has something to do with the question mark (**?**) in the expression.

I've also tried an online java regex tool and applied the expression on some text with the following characters ***‘”***. It didn't show any error.

I've also tried writing a simple test method in online java compiler where I passed a test string with the ***‘”*** characters and performed the above-mentioned split. No error either.

Code:

```
String answerText = uiq.getAnswerText();
            if (answerText.matches("[\\x00-\\x7F]*")) //if the answerString consists only of ascii characters we encode it
                sb.append("<String name=\"answerText\">")
                        .append(wrapCdata(uiq.isDate() ? formatDate(uiq.getAnswerText(), sourceFormat, targetFormat) : answerText)).append("</String>");
            else { //if the answerString consists of unicode characters we encode only the Linebreakers (the \R)
                String answerNonEscapedText = "";
                String[] unicodeStrings = answerText.split("((?<=\\R)|(?=\\R))");//This regex splits the string to its linebreak-delimiters, including them. i.e. ("$$$\r\n" ---> [$,$,$,\r\n])
                for (String str : unicodeStrings) {
                    if (str.matches("\\R"))
                        str = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(str);

                    answerNonEscapedText += str;
                }
```

Error:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 6 
((?<=\R)|(?=\R)) 
 ^ 
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1924) 
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.escape(Pattern.java:2416) 
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.atom(Pattern.java:2164) 
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2046) 
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1964) 
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:2807) 
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2018) 
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1964) 
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:2854) 
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2018) 
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1964) 
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1665) 
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1337) 
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1022) 
 at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2313) 
 at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2355)
```

Could you please help me finding the root cause of the failure?

Comment: `"((?<=\\R)|(?=\\R))"` contains both a look-ahead and look-behind 0 width match, and that as group. `"\\R"` for newline should suffice. You will not get the line separating chars ("\n", "\r\n", "\r" or "\u0085") though. look-behind and ahead probably were done for receiving the line separator and maybe for the last line.

Answer (score 1):

```
        String answerText = uiq.getAnswerText();
        if (answerText.matches("[\\x00-\\x7F]*")) {
            sb.append("<String name=\"answerText\">")
              .append(wrapCdata(uiq.isDate()
                      ? formatDate(uiq.getAnswerText(), sourceFormat, targetFormat)
                      : answerText))
              .append("</String>");
        } else {
            String[] unicodeStrings = answerText.split("\\R"); // Splits on linebreaks.
            // This looses the exact line delimiter.
            String answerNonEscapedText = ""; // Better StringBuilder too.
            for (String str : unicodeStrings) {
                answerNonEscapedText += str + "\\r\\n";
            }
```

For some cases the above loss of the original line delimiters is important: there exists CSV where a field value may contain line separators `\n` whereas the line ends in `\r\n`. Or such.

A simpler solution:

```
        // Java >= 9
        String answerText = Pattern.compile("\\R").matcher(uiq.getAnswerText())
            .replaceAll(mr -> StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(mr.group()));


        // Java < 9 (only for \r and \n)
        String answerText = uiq.getAnswerText()
            .replace("\r", "\\r").replace("\n", "\\n");
```

Comment: *(Hanging my head at somehow having missed `\R` despite **searching** the pattern page...)*

Comment: Thanks for reviewing and upgrading the code, Joop. The expression was, however, correct and I'll probably not going to refactor it.
The root cause was dumber than I anticipated.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the regex expression was not incorrect. It was, however, supported only by java 8+ and I had java 7 on my environment. An upgrade of java solved the issue.

> ## Pattern (Java Platform SE 7)
>
> Perl constructs not supported by this class:
>
> Predefined character classes (Unicode character)
>
> \h    A horizontal whitespace
>
> \H    A non horizontal whitespace
>
> \v    A vertical whitespace
>
> \V    A non vertical whitespace
>
> **\R    Any Unicode linebreak sequence** \u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]
>
> \X    Match Unicode extended grapheme cluster